# Databricks fails accessing a Data Lake Gen1 while trying to enumerate a directory

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am using (well... trying to use) Azure Databricks and I have created a notebook.

I would like the notebook to connect my Azure Data Lake (Gen1) and transform the data. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html#access-adls-using-the-dataframe-api) and put the code in the first cell of my notebook:

```
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", "**using the application ID of the registered application**")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", "**using one of the registered application keys**")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/**using my-tenant-id**/oauth2/token")

dbutils.fs.ls("adl://**using my data lake uri**.azuredatalakestore.net/tenantdata/events")
```

The execution fails with this error:

> com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Error enumerating
>   directory /
>
> Operation null failed with exception java.io.IOException : Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/**using my-tenant-id**/oauth2/token
>   Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries.
>
> [java.io.IOException,java.io.IOException,java.io.IOException,java.io.IOException,java.io.IOException]
>   [ServerRequestId:null]    at
>   com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.getExceptionFromResponse(ADLStoreClient.java:1169)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.enumerateDirectoryInternal(ADLStoreClient.java:558)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.enumerateDirectory(ADLStoreClient.java:534)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.enumerateDirectory(ADLStoreClient.java:398)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.enumerateDirectory(ADLStoreClient.java:384)

I have given the registered application the `Reader` role to the Data Lake:

[image]

**Question**

How can I allow Spark to access the Data Lake?

**Update**

I have granted both the `tenantdata` and `events` folders `Read` and `Execute` access:

[image: Granted persmissions on folder]

Comment: Maybe try setting the application to the `Contributor` role instead of `Reader`.

Answer (score 1):

The RBAC roles on the Gen1 lake do not grant access to the data (just the resource itself), with exception of the Owner role which grants Super User access and does grant full data access.

You must grant access to the folders/files themselves using Data Explorer in the Portal or download storage explorer using POSIX permissions.

This guide explains the detail of how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data

> Only the Owner role automatically enables file system access. The
>   Contributor, Reader, and all other roles require ACLs to enable any
>   level of access to folders and files

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did have the permissions on both folders... :(

Comment: You must have at least Execute permission on every folder above the folder you are trying to access (including root).

Comment: The root, the tenantdata folder and the events folder all do have the Read and Execute permission... :(

Comment: As a test can you add your principal to the owner group on the resource. If that works then you have missed a folder permission somewhere.